# Как отображать всплывающую подсказку при наведении курсора на SVG-элемент

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, svg

Мне нужна встроенная SVG-диаграмма с иконкой «дополнительная информация», при наведении на которую,  должна появляться  всплывающая подсказка. Смотри иллюстрацию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть всплывающая подсказка, реализованная в стилях div, которая используется в других местах, но мне также нужно, чтобы она запускалась при наведении на иконку `дополнительная информация` внутри SVG.

Я знаю, что не могу добавить html всплывающую подсказку в SVG.
Какие еще варианты доступны мне?
"chart" - это просто встроенный SVG, взятый непосредственно из графического редпктора (в данном случае Sketch).
Я не использую какие-либо фреймворки или библиотеки, такие как D3 или chartjs. Пожалуйста, не предлагайте использовать библиотеки или фреймворки, поскольку это не вариант для меня.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to display a tooltip div when an SVG element is hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46384057/7394871) от участника  [@user1275105](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1275105/user1275105).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/46384057/7394871

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все очень просто. Для этого требуется всего несколько строк Javascript.

Когда мы наводим курсор на иконку, мы вызываем всплывающее окно и показываем его. При уходе курсора мы снова скрываем его.
Также обратите внимание на `pointer-events="all"` на иконке, который гарантирует, что мышь будет считаться "над" элементом иконки даже для битов, которые имеют невидимую заливку.

```js
var myicon = document.getElementById("myicon");
var mypopup = document.getElementById("mypopup");

myicon.addEventListener("mouseover", showPopup);
myicon.addEventListener("mouseout", hidePopup);

function showPopup(evt) {
  var iconPos = myicon.getBoundingClientRect();
  mypopup.style.left = (iconPos.right + 20) + "px";
  mypopup.style.top = (window.scrollY + iconPos.top - 60) + "px";
  mypopup.style.display = "block";
}

function hidePopup(evt) {
  mypopup.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #33333f;
}

#mypopup {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

#mypopup::before {
  content: "";
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -6px;
  top: 68px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <g id="myicon" pointer-events="all">
    <circle cx="100" cy="150" r="14" fill="none" stroke="gold" stroke-width="2"/>
    <circle cx="100" cy="144" r="2" fill="gold"/>
    <rect x="98.5" y="148" width="3" height="10" fill="gold"/>
  </g>
</svg>

<div id="mypopup">
  <h3>Popup title</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46386620/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>